# amazon product advertising API Update issues

Tags: c#, .net, amazon-web-services, sample

I'm trying to get into the Amazon advertizing API to use with one of my apps. I heard recently that there were changes and needed an AssociateTag (broughtin from the affiliate program)

After using samples from this link 
http://aws.amazon.com/code/2480?_encoding=UTF8&queryArg=searchQuery&x=0&fromSearch=1&y=0&searchPath=code&searchQuery=Advertising

and 
http://flyingpies.wordpress.com/2009/08/13/signing-amazon-product-advertising-api-cwcf-part-2/

I can't seem to use those samples anymore. after some digging online I found that I was supposed to add an AssociateTag to the itemSource request variable, but I created a dummy login to facilitate that andthe output is pretty much the same. can anyone help me with this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I had the exact same issue as I based my application on the flyingpies.wordpress example and couldn't get it to work by adding in the Associate Tag Id and the latest web service>

I downloaded this example:

http://aws.amazon.com/code/Product-Advertising-API/2481

And made some small changes and got it all working...

The main one changing the namespace to:

http://webservices.amazon.com/AWSECommerceService/2011-08-01

Throughout all the code......

I think I may have updated the code in a couple of other places and can help you if these errors occur..

Comment: I used the REST API, but it asks for AssociateTag. I'm trying to get that up, and will post changes needed here. but I changed the link to yours for it to start working. so the answer is partially correct.

Comment: http://aws.amazon.com/code/Product-Advertising-API/2480

THis sample with an AssociateTag set by registering to the affiliate program and changing the version dates to yours works perfectly.